# Do the other universes know that it was Universe 7 that wished them back using Super Dragon Balls?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

It was Universe 7 that wished other Universes back using Super Dragon Balls.

Maybe Universe 6 & 11 knows it, but what about the other universes?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answer would be yes!
 The angels of all the universes indeed witnessed Universe 7 winning the tournament and they would be going back to their respective universes, so it would only make sense for their respective Universe to find out irrespective of whether they knew beforehand. It would be a very obvious question asked by the gods to the angels considering they were revived all of a sudden  and witnessed the Super Dragon Balls being used.